# Get Object to Appear in Front of Rotated Object in JavaFX, and then Launch

Tags: java, javafx, rotation, transform, coordinate

I have an object that I rotate in JavaFX, in this case a Rectangle. I want to make a second Rectangle, that appears based on mouse click, right in front of the "top" of my 1st rectangle. This works fine when the first rectangle has not rotated, but once there is a rotation, the coordinates are not right. Here's some sample code:

```
rec2.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(theta, rec1.getX() + 50, rec1.getY() -  72.5));
```

Theta is the angle of rotation. How do I make the second rectangle always appear in front, instead of a a higher/lower x/y position? This may require math...

To be more clear:

```
If theta = 90, then(rec2's y position) is (rec1's y position - 10)//up by 10
           (rec2's x position) is (rec1's x position)
If theta = 0, then(rec2's y position) is (rec1's y position)
           (rec2's x position) is (rec1's x position + 10)//right by 10
and so forth for every angle 0 <=theta < 360.
```

Then, I want to launch it forward with a constant velocity. I thought of how I might do this but it didn't work (this is in my mouse button click handler):

```
            double slope = Math.tan(theta);
            rec2.setY(rec1.getX() * slope);
            rec2.setX(rec1.getY() / slope);
```

Comment: This question is not particularly clear.  What does "in front" mean in this context?  Usually in front means something is painted on top of something else (z-order wise) - but I am not sure that is your meaning.

Comment: My guess is that you don't understand the [JavaFX bounding rectangles which are documented for Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) and are performing layout calculations on transformed nodes based on a Node's [layoutBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutBoundsProperty--) rather than a Node's [boundsInParent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty--)

Comment: in front meaning let's say I decided to make the rectangle a person with a head, or a spaceship. I always want the second rectangle to appear in front of the object, as in, on top, because it's in two dimensions. However, if the spaceship rotates 45 degrees, without the spaceship moving, then the coordinates for place the rectangle "in front" of the spaceship are not the same.

Comment: You might want to place all the shapes in a Group, and then apply the transforms (such as the rotation) to the Group.